# Right way to define Procfile for Nuxt + Php application

Tags: php, heroku, vue.js, nuxt.js

I've created an application with Nuxt.js for SSR, and PHP for REST API. The folder structure is:

- client (for Node.js)
- server (for PHP)

After researching I found out that in Procfile process type should be defined as `<process type>: <command>`. But, how can I run my app with this folder structure? For client command is `npm run start` and for server is `php -S localhost:8181 -t public public/index.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Procfile` entries need to have different names, and [the `web` process is the only one that receives HTTP traffic](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#declaring-process-types). So to have two `web` processes you need to split the two backends into different Heroku apps.

Comment: But why I can't just do `web: npm run start` and `api: php -S localhost:8181 -t public public/index.php` in the root Procfile? Or something like that...

Comment: Because only the `web` process is exposed to the outside, and you need both `web` and `api` to be able to receive HTTP traffic for your app to work. Entries other than `web` in the `Procfile` are useful for daemons, maintenance scripts and other "internal" stuff, but cannot expose ports to the outside, so they can't be used as outside-facing HTTP servers. TBH, someone actually managed to trick Heroku into exposing multiple processes, but as you can imagine it's not sanctioned nor easy to do: https://medium.com/@nadayar/heroku-fu-multiple-servers-on-one-dyno-6fc68d57b373